# Проблема с array_rand

Tags: php

```
if ($sex == 1){
                $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные мужские скины
                $model = array_rand($skin);
}
if ($sex == 2){
                $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные женские скины
                $model = array_rand($skin);
}
```

Помогите, при var_dump($model) пишет NULL

Comment: попробуйте по старинке если `array_rand` не срабатывает `$model = rand(0, count($skin) - 1);` и покажите как вы `$sex` получаете задампите и покажите пост

Comment: И попробуйте сделать так `if ($sex == 1){
                $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные мужские скины
                $model = array_rand($skin);
}elseif ($sex == 2){
                $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные женские скины
                $model = array_rand($skin);
} else var_dump($sex);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data['sex'] = '1';

switch ($data['sex']) {
    case 1:
        $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5);
        $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
        break;
    case 2:
        $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5);
        $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

var_dump($model);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ - вводим сюда и жмякаем на `Execute Code`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80854/discussion-on-answer-by-manitikyl---array-rand).

Answer (score 2):

```
$model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
```

Comment: Всё равно null выводит

Comment: А вы уверены, что условие `$sex == 1 (2)` срабатывает вообще?

Comment: @МаксимХалин, и вообще лучше использовать [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: $data = $_POST; - Переназначаю
Даже если так
if ($data['sex'] == 1){
    $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные мужские скины
    $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
   }
   if ($data['sex'] == 2){
    $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные женские скины
    $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
   }

Comment: Даже если так, то всё равно не работает

Comment: @МаксимХалин работает код ваш. Включите вывод ошибок. Скорее всего $sex не приходит.

Comment: $data['sex'] приходит, проверил с помощью Var dump

Comment: @МаксимХалин, приходит цифрой? Ну так проверяйте тогда `if ($data['sex'] == 1) { ... }`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie string(1) "2"

Comment: @МаксимХалин, у вас приходит строкой, проверяйте так: `if ($sex == '1') { ... }` или `if ( (int) $sex == 1) { ... }`

Comment: @МаксимХалин, и не стоит путать `string` с `int`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie if ($data['sex'] == '1') проверяю вот так, всё равно NULL

Comment: Ну может быть потому, что ты указал так условие для `== 1`, а другое условие  `== 2` не тронул, ведь тебе `2` приходит?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie "01" == 1 будет true тут же не тождественное

Comment: @Let'ssayPie я и '2' тоже сделал всё равно NULL

Comment: if ($data['sex'] == '1'){
    $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные мужские скины
    $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
}if ($data['sex'] == '2'){
    $skin = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Рандомные женские скины
    $model = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
   }